# Including or not resources depending on the value of directive "const" in Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have a #const directive configured in a VB.NET project.
I use its value for compiling or not piece of code. Its value is "A" or "B" (for instance)
I have several files (images) in two folders "A" and "B". All of these images have got assigned the property "Copy to output folder" > "Copy always".

My cuestión is: How could I include only the included file in "A" or "B" folder depending on the #const value when the project is compiled?

Comment: What do you mean by "include"? Do you mean just read a specific folder or do you want only that folder to be "Copy to output folder" ?

Comment: I only want "Copy to output folder" files of folder "A" or "B" depending on the value of #const directive, or depending any const which is configured before compiling the solution/project.